# Busqueda con array en mongodb con nodejs

Tags: nodejs, api, mongodb

Estoy creando una restFull api con nodejs y mongodb. Estoy intentando hacer una consulta en mongodb y nodejs, pero no consigo la forma. El problema lo tengo en buscar sobre el array categorías que llega por parámetro, intengo hacer el $in sobre el array y se me queda pillado.

```
exports.getAlertasDistritoCategoria = (distrito, categorias) =>

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    alerta.find({distrito: distrito, categoria:{$in:categorias}}).sort({fecha:-1})
    .then(alertas => categorias)

    .catch(err => reject({status: 500, message: 'Internal Server Error! verAlertasDistritoCategoria.js'}))


});
```

Comment: Creo que debes pasar una matriz cuando usas `$` algo como esto: `db.coll.find({"tags" : { $in : ['etc1']  } } );`

Comment: Gracias, pero categorias se esta pasando como un array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta se ve bien, pero en el `.then(alertas => categorias)` faltaría el `resolve`. Ej:

```
exports.getAlertasDistritoCategoria = (distrito, categorias) => (
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        alerta
            .find({distrito: distrito, categoria:{$in:categorias}}).sort({fecha:-1})
            .then((alertas) => {
                resolve(alertas); // o tambien resolve(categorias) si deseas retornar categorias
            })
            .catch(err => reject({status: 500, message: 'Internal Server Error! verAlertasDistritoCategoria.js'}))
    })  
)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, de esta forma si que me funciona :)